# Folland Problem 2.33 Question (Fatou's Lemma for Convergence in Measure)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Here is problem 2.33 from Folland's *Real Analysis*:

> If $f_n \geq 0$ and $f_n \to f$ in measure, then $\int f \leq \liminf \int f_n$.

I managed to work out a proof in the $\sigma$-finite case, as follows. My question, however, is how one might be able to disregard the $\sigma$-finite condition, which the problem statement suggests is possible. I would appreciate a small *hint*, and not a full solution (which is why I am avoiding other similar questions on this site). Of course, if there is a major flaw in my current proof I would love to hear that, too.

First, we observe that $f\geq 0$ a.e. To see this, for $m\geq 1$ consider the sequence of sets $A_m = \{x : f(x) \leq -m^{-1}\}$. Then $A_m \subset \{x : f_n(x) - f(x) \geq m^{-1}\}$, hence $\mu(A_m) \leq \mu(\{x : f_n(x) - f(x) \geq m^{-1}\}) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. In particular, $\mu(A_m) = 0$. Since $A_m$ increases to the set $\{x : f(x) < 0\}$, taking $m\to \infty$ implies that $\mu(\{x : f(x) < 0\}) = 0$.

Next, let $\{E_j\}$ be a sequence of measurable sets with finite measure such that $E_j \subset E_{j+1}$ and $\lim \mu(E_j) = \mu(X)$. Let $A_j = \{x\in E_j: f(x) \leq j\}$. Since $A_j$ increases to $X$, there is $J$ large enough that $\mu(A_j) > 0$ for $j\geq J$.  For these $A_j$, we note that $f\in L^1$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$, and set $\epsilon' = \epsilon/(2\mu(A_j))$. There exists $N\geq 1$ large enough that
$$\int_{\{x \in A_j : |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon'\}} f\,d\mu < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$ for every $n\geq N$. We can also require $N$ large enough that $\mu(\{x \in A_j : |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon'\}) < \varepsilon/2$ for every $n\geq N$. Then it holds
$$\int_{A_j} f = \int_{|f_n - f| \geq \epsilon'} f + \int_{|f_n - f| < \epsilon'} f \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \int_{|f_n - f| < \epsilon'} f_n + \frac{\epsilon}{2\mu(A_j)}\mu(A_j) \leq \epsilon + \int f_n. \quad (*)$$
Thus taking the $\liminf$ over $n$ yields
$$\int_{A_j} f \leq \liminf_{n\to \infty} \int f_n + \epsilon.$$
Finally, since $A_j \nearrow X$, taking $j\to \infty$ yields
$$\int f \,d\mu \leq \liminf_{n\to \infty} \int f_n + \epsilon,$$
and since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary the proof is done.

The main difficultly in foregoing the $\sigma$-finite condition for me has been in inequality $(*)$. If $X$ is not $\sigma$-finite then we would have $\mu(\{ x : |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon\}) = \infty$ for every $n$ (since $\mu(x : |f_n(x) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon\}) < \infty$), in which case the rest of the proof breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\lim \inf \int f_n d\mu < \int f d\mu$. Let $\lim \inf \int f_n d\mu < c< \int f d\mu$. Pick $(n_i)$ increasing to $\infty$  such that $\lim \int f_{n_i}d\mu <c$. Choose a further subsequence of  $(f_{n_i})$ which converges a.e. Apply Fatou's Lemma to this subsequence of  $(f_{n_i})$ to finish.